# A $3\times3$ ColorSaw

Tags: logical-deduction, visual

The pieces of this ColorSaw have been flipped, rotated and moved.

Can you reassemble the puzzle so that each adjacent side has the same color/shape?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Answer is:

> [image: Answer]

I just fixed the first picture and arranged the others according to it.